# Why don't preferred profiles work for WSo2 API Manager 1.6.0?

Tags: wso2

While working on WSo2 API Manager 1.5.0 and 1.6.0 I noticed that when attempting to run the commands to launch the service using the "start" or "restart" options and later would do a 
"ps -ef | grep Dprofile" I would get no results back.  Which indicates that the services were NOT being launched in a preferred profile.

Referrencing: http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Running+the+Product+on+a+Preferred+Profile

Why doesn't this start up work?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the document never mentions the "start" or "restart" commands for the Linux version.
When I dug into "wso2server.sh" I noticed that using the "start" or "restart" command calls the command:

```
"nohup bash $CARBON_HOME/bin/wso2server.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Notice that the previous command line arguements when you make a call like:

```
#./wso2server.sh -Dprofile=api-key-manager start
```

The shell script consumes your arguements and does not forward them in the next call to the script, which then finally executes the actual start of java with all of the options at the bottom of the shell script.

To fix this you would need to update the script to strip out the "start", "restart", etc commands and then pass the remaining arguements in the next call.

Or you can never/ever use the "start" or "restart" commands with the script.